# angular firebase saving data as object

Tags: angularjs, firebase

its my first time using angular with firebase.

I am having a hard time saving data as an object to firebase.

whenever i save a data, it doesn't provide index id or random generated id.
so first time name it saves the data and second time it overwrites the data because of not having any id.

here is my code

```
myApp.controller('MeetingsController', ['$scope','$firebaseObject', function ($scope, $firebaseObject) {

     var ref = new Firebase('https://saddam.firebaseio.com/employees');
     var obj = $firebaseObject(ref);
     $scope.meetings = obj;

     $scope.meetings.$loaded(function() {
        console.log(obj);
     });

     $scope.addMeeting = function() {
         obj.userinfo= {
            meetingName : $scope.meetingname,
            date : Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
        }

        obj.$save();
     }
}]);
```

Looking for some help

Comment: Your `employees` refers to a collection, so you should use `$firebaseArray` instead of `$firebaseObject`. After doing that your  `addMeeting` method can call `$add` instead of `$save`. Please take a moment to follow the AngularFire quickstart, which covers this in step 5: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html. While there, also note that `console.log` is an error-prone way of debugging AngularFire apps. Instead just put this in your HTML: `<pre>{{ meetings | json }}</pre>`

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked and i was able to create my test app.

Comment: However when i import my app to phonegap, it doesn't save any data. i am compiling my app through phonegap website directly.